# Custom List View is taking too much time on page load react native

Tags: react-native, listview

I need some help. I've made a custom list view with some animation (drag and drop). everything is working fine except when there is large number of data, its taking too much time to load the page/when navigating back from another page. Is there any technique where I can reduce the page loading time? Please do not suggest any external packages, and also I cannot use flatlist either, due to my Animated.Scrollview conflicting with Flatlist own Scrollview. I've searched online, and everyone is using flatlist, which i cannot use. Or is it possible to ignore FlatList Own ScrollView?
[image]

Comment: if it is there large number of data, use pagination.

Comment: The list has drag and drop feature, So I cannot use pagination

Comment: your list view might have some of the functions that using in flatlist. So just take a look at this doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

here you can get some idea

Comment: Can I also use those props in my custom list Scrollview?

Comment: some of the methods are same in scrollview and flatlist.

Comment: That didn't help, Is there any way i can push my animated code to flatlist scrollview?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239981/discussion-between-alauddin-ahmed-and-manojkanth).

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternate solution [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/457). You can use FlatList for larger data. Then pass your Animated.ScrollView component as a props through FlatList.

```
renderScrollComponent={(props) => (
    <Animated.ScrollView
      {...props}
      onScroll={(event) => {
        onScroll({ y: feedScroll })(event)
        props.onScroll(event)
      }}
    />
  )}
```